# What items are only available during the Halloween Event?

Tags: terraria

The [Halloween Event](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Halloween_Event) goes until November 10, and I'm wondering what items I should try to focus on getting until that time. I've been spending time trying to obtain [Goodie Bags](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goodie_Bag), which drop a number of vanity items. But what other Halloween-specific items are only available during the Halloween Event? I know that certain NPC's sell unique items, but what should I buy before they disappear?

Comment: If you miss anything there's always the option of setting your system clock to get Halloween mode active in the game again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Halloween Mode specific items:

**NPCs**:

- *The Merchant*: sells a sickle for 1 gold.  When used to cut grass, it harvests hay.
- *The Arms Dealer*: sells the nurse's outfit (hat, shirt, pants), 3 gold per item.
- *Witch Doctor*: sells the cauldron for 1.5 gold.  This is basically a re-skinned cooking pot.

**Drops**:

- Bloody Machette,  a harpoon category weapon.  This has a .05% drop chance.
- Bladed Glove, a claw weapon with high knockback.  This is also a .05% drop chance.
- Goodie Bags, of course.  They drop 1.25% of the time.

The only other difference in Halloween Mode is that pumpkins grow naturally on grass surfaces.  You can now buy pumpkin seeds year round though, so you'll always have access to pumpkins if you have money to spend.